# AbstractRoutingDataSource & Transactional Managers

Tags: java, spring, datasource, spring-transactions

I currently have a program which has two data sources. Each of the data source is tied to one transactional manager.

```
<bean id="tM" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds1" />
</bean>

<bean id="tM2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds2" />
</bean>
```

If I had a function that accesses both datasource and an error occurs, if one datasource rollbacks would the second data source would also rollback?

Thanks!

Comment: Just dont commit unless transactions on both databases are complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function access datastores sequentialy (I mean it make COMMIT to the first datastore and try to COMMIT to the second one) then if error occur after first COMMIT, second data source will do ROLLBACK, but first - stay COMMITED

So, you must use one data store or JTATransactionManager.

Answer (score 1):

Spring can't rollback a committed JDBC statment. This is what XADataSources and 2 phase commit are for (usually through a JTA TX manager).

You are asking for data inconsistency trying to manage this yourself because this may or may not work depending on what fails when. For example, assume this flow:

- Start TX
- Do work with ds1
- Do work with ds2
- End TX

  - commit ds2
  - commit ds1

If the commit on ds1 fails, then ds2 will stay commited. But, if the commit on ds2 fails, then the whole tx will fail and ds1 will rollback.

Also, are you sure you are always closing the DataSources in the same order they were open (first used)? Spring may take care of this, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Autocommit may be on by default. Consider setting this off and managing the commits yourself .